How do I know when I am ready to move on to the next piece?
I am practicing playing the piano, and I have gotten quite good at playing the current piece, good enough to see where to put fingers to play it better. But it is not flawlessly perfect.
But I have also gotten quite bored playing at it, so should I move on to the next piece?

Did anyone ever tell you that you have to continue to work on only one single piece till it’s “flawlessly perfect” before you move on to another one? That is certainly not the case!

I second @JohnBelzaguy.  See also my recent answer.

I'd say being bored is a very strong indication that you must change something.  If you are satisfied with the result, move on.  The best players I know got to their level not because they were super disciplined but because they really liked doing it.

Just make sure you don't pick a piece which is way too difficult for you. I spent way too much time learning some pieces for which I didn't have the level (both in playing and in music sheet reading). Now I can play them relatively comfortably but I don't feel like learning any more sheets for a good while.

I approach learning music in three phases:

Go through the piece to get a sense of how it will sound, how it's constructed, difficult passages — to form an overall sense of how I would want to perform the piece.

Practice the piece until I can play it reasonably well — enough to feel I've learned what it has to offer.

Polish the piece to performance level. I only do this if I'm actually going to perform it. Otherwise, I'd rather move on to another piece so that I can keep learning new things.



It very much depends what your aims actually are - no mention of them!
If it's just to experience pieces, and know what each is about, then learn them until you can play at a reasonable speed, not forgetting their dynamics (often overlooked), without more than a couple of mistakes. You may decide to perform them for family and friends, which will give loads of real pressure, and be a good yardstick as to whether you actually can play them.
You may want to record them, at which point there's possibly even more pressure to get them correct, if only for you to listen back. Another benchmark is can you play it without looking at the keyboard, or without reference to the dots?
With some of my students, I only wanted to hear a good rendition of certain parts of pieces, as they were the focus of the particular skill we were working on, so some pieces never were completed. That suited both of us, but may not suit you and/or teacher. Just an idea.
From a personal practical point of view, when learning piano, all I ever did with several different teachers was to learn the specific things for the next exam, which very nearly killed any enthusiasm I had for the instrument. Lesson learned there - both physically and metaphorically...

It is good to focus on a piece, but it is also good to not focus on a single piece. Sometimes you head needs some time off from a piece to not get stuck up. Instead of moving on to a different piece, maybe just start a new piece, and spend some time learning pieces, some time polishing your other pieces. Taking your mind off a piece for a bit can return a lot of motivation and can allow you to develop new approaches to a piece.
It is not good to divert between too many pieces, but having a few (and even if it is just 2-3 pieces) you work on at the same time is a good thing.
But when to stop? Well, you’d need to ask yourself: Why am I practicing this piece? If you do it because you like playing it — surely you are not going to completely stop playing it. Are you practicing it to develop technique? Then there is no need to get it perfected, rather you want to focus on the parts that are training the technique in the first place. Are you practicing for a recital? Or is this going to be a repertoire piece you might dig out and polish for a recital?
All in all there is no clear boundary on how far you should take a piece.

You're bored.  That's an excellent reason to play something else.  But play it as well, not instead of.   It's not a journey from one piece to another, it's about building up a repertoire!
Re-visit some of the stuff you learnt last year.  Now these pieces are 'easy', can you find some more music in them, rather than just getting through without mistakes?
